# AbortProcessingException into Jsf ActionListener cause Servlet Exception

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I have a problem working with actionListener into primefaces commandbutton. 
An error occurs when an AbortProccessingException is thrown in an ActionListener that causes the application to stop working, and ignore if other buttons are pressed. It is important to say that it is a migrated project from Java 1.6 to Java 1.8 and that when the project was in Java 1.6 it worked perfectly. The error displayed by the console is the following:

```
####<18-may-2020 11H01' CEST> <Error> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context> <PC12408> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <18039576-aeb0-4dcc-af77-6a081205f46c-00000029> <1589792493940> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <jsf.context.exception.handler.log> <JSF1073: se ha interceptado javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException durante el procesamiento de APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2 : UIComponent-ClientId=medicionesForm:testListerner, Mensaje=null> 
####<18-may-2020 11H01' CEST> <Error> <HTTP> <PC12408> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <18039576-aeb0-4dcc-af77-6a081205f46c-00000029> <1589792493940> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@1917730584[app:FGDOLNG-ear module:FGDOLNG path:null spec-version:3.1]] Servlet failed with an Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.PropertyResourceBundle.handleGetObject(PropertyResourceBundle.java:166)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:441)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:407)
    at java.util.logging.Formatter.formatMessage(Formatter.java:118)
    at com.bea.logging.BaseLogger.formatMessage(BaseLogger.java:70)
    at weblogic.logging.WLLogger.normalizeLogRecord(WLLogger.java:74)
    at weblogic.logging.WLLogger.log(WLLogger.java:31)
    at weblogic.logging.ServerLoggingHandler.publish(ServerLoggingHandler.java:51)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:876)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.log(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:256)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:137)
    at javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:72)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
>
```

And this is my code:

```
<p:commandButton id="testListerner" value="Test Listener"
                        styleClass="botonGris fL" style="width:150px;" tabindex="5"
                        actionListener="#{mybean.testListener()}"
                        action="#{mybean.testAction()}">
</p:commandButton>
```

And my java code:

```
public void testListener() throws AbortProcessingException{
        FacesUtil.addMessageFaces(this.messagesFromMbID, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Test Message", null); 
        throw new AbortProcessingException();
    }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: The stack trace is incomplete but it suggests that you're using WebLogic server and that something in its exception handling/logging internals is failing to find a resource bundle. This is not a JSF problem and absolutely not a PrimeFaces problem.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for your answer. I did not put the complete trace of the error, right now I edit my question and include that information. You are right it is not a problem of primefaces, sorry is my first question in Stack Overflow.